# Add Country code to URL along with Language code

Tags: sitecore, multilingual

The requirement is to have country code in the URL along with the Language code.

Please suggest me the best approach to have country code in URL.

we set "languageEmbedding="always"" the Sitecore adds language code to URL, but our requirement is to include country code as well in the URL.

example : sitename/zh-tw/tw/pagename

**Updated:**

I have added country code to URL by overrding the "ItemUrlBuilder"

```
 public class ResolveURL : ItemUrlBuilder
    {
        public ResolveURL(DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions defaultOptions) : base(defaultOptions)
        {
        }
        public override string Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            if (Context.Site == null || Context.Site.Name == "shell" || !Context.Language.ToString().Contains("-"))
            {
                return base.Build(item, options);
            }
            options.LanguageEmbedding = Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Always;
            var countryCode = Context.Language.ToString().Split('-')[1];
            var newLangCode = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", Context.Language, countryCode);

            var itemUrl = base.Build(item, options).Replace(Context.Language.ToString().ToLower(), newLangCode.ToLower());

            return itemUrl;
        }

    }
```

It is adding country code to URL Sitename/zh-tw/tw/pagename

And Then i have override the "HttpRequestProcessor" to resolve the URL with country code "tw"

```
public class LanguageResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            if (Context.Site.Name == "mySitename" && Context.Language.ToString().Contains("-"))
            {

                if (args != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Url.ItemPath) && Context.Item == null)
                {
                    var countryCode = Context.Language.ToString().Split('-')[1].ToLower();
                    var countrycode = string.Concat("/", countryCode);
                    var ItemPath = args.Url.ItemPath.Replace(countrycode, "");

                    Context.Item = Context.Database.GetItem(ItemPath, Context.Language);
                   
                }

            }
        }
```

Even though am getting the correct Itempath, "Context.Database.GetItem(ItemPath, Context.Language);" gives me 404 error page and gives Item is null.

The strange thing is for " sitename/zh-tw/tw/ " it gives home page correct, but for other pages it gives Item as null.

Please suggest me what am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest is to create a Custom Link Provider by extending the existing one i.e.

```
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.LinkManagers.LocalizableLinkProvider, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite
```

And you need to modify the method called `GetItemUrl` by adding the country code in the URL.

And place this using a patch file.

And then need to extend the existing Item resolver

```
Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel
```

to resolve the URL by removing the country code from the URL.

Hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Please check i have updated the post, am getting null for GetItem(path,context.language) except for home page

Comment: @ParvathiSomanahalli I would suggest to debug your code i.e. `Context.Item = Context.Database.GetItem(ItemPath, Context.Language);` where you need to pass the itemPath without the language code and then it will resolve your item. Because Sitecore is trying to resolve the item using the correct path but in your case it doesn't found.

Comment: The Item is null even after removing the "Context.Language" from GetItem method, but its working only for home page with url "https://mysite.dev.local/zh-tw/tw" and i have debug my code and Context.Item is null for other pages except home page.

Comment: @ParvathiSomanahalli What if you pass the exact item URL without language and country code? In that case, also you get null? What URL did you get in `args.Url.ItemPath` ?

Comment: If i pass page url directly to GetItem i am getting same 404 error. args.Url.ItemPath initially will have "/tw" but in code i have removed that, after the final url will be without "/tw", am passing url without "/tw" to GetItem, but some how "/tw" its getting added not sure how.

Comment: I have enabled Item Level language fallback and when i load the page ex: "https://mysite.dev.local/zh-tw/page without "/tw" loads fine means page has version for zh-tw language. but how "/tw" is getting added to url even after i removed it is the problem, not sure how its happening.

Comment: @ParvathiSomanahalli Is it something caching? Can you remove your cache and check again?

Comment: args.Url.ItemPath has "-" in itempath once i removed "-" from item path pages are loading with zh-tw/tw in the url's, expageurl : "https://mysite.dev.local/zh-tw/tw/in-experience/new-premium-class" removed "-" from page urls "/in-experience/new-premium-class", now page loading